# Physical meaning of $\langle 0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0 \rangle$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, partition-function, s-matrix-theory

when I am reading text book Introduction to Many body physics Piers Coleman 2nd editor, Equation (5.26). I got confused about the meaning of  $\langle0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle$.

---

first problem

$|0\rangle$ is the static ground state of $H_0$

$S(+\infty,-\infty)$ is time evolution in Interacting Picture, and the total Hamiltonian is given by $H=H_0+V e^{-\epsilon |t|}$, both $H_0$ and $V$ are static, usually $[H_0,V]\neq 0$

So, $|\Psi\rangle_I=S(0,-\infty)|0\rangle$ should be the ground state of $H$,

similarly $\langle\Psi|_I=\langle0|S(+\infty,0)$

then $\langle0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle=_I\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle_I   := e^{2i\delta}$

or say $|\langle0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle|^2=|\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle|^2 =1$  **very trivial, why do we need to calculate it ?**

or perhaps $\delta=\delta(V,H_0)$ is something interesting?

---

second problem

extend $H=H_0+V e^{-\epsilon |t|}$ to the more general case $H=H_0+V(t)$, now we don't have $|\Psi,t=0\rangle$ interpreted as the ground state of some $H+V(t=0)$, this is because near $t=0$, $V(t)$ may oscillate a lot, not as smooth as the adiabatic $V e^{-\epsilon |T|}$. And in general $|\langle0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle|^2 \neq 1 \leq 1$

then what is the meaning of calculating:
$\langle0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle=\langle0|T e^{-i \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dt V_I(t) }|0\rangle$  as given by Equation (5.26) in text book Introduction to Many body physics Piers Coleman 2nd editor ? the book says, the meaning is the **probability amplitude to stay in the same ground state after the influence  $V(t)$**  ,  but I think the correct answer should be

$$\langle S,-\infty|S,+\infty \rangle   \qquad .......(1)  \checkmark $$
 rather than 
$$\langle I,-\infty|I,+\infty \rangle = \langle0|S(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle   \qquad .......(2)  $$

where: 
$$   |S,-\infty \rangle = |H,-\infty \rangle =|I,-\infty \rangle  := |0\rangle 
$$

after some calculation with help of $|S,t>=e^{-iH_0 t}|I,t>$, we can show that the difference between (1) and (2) is 
$$   (1) = (2) e^{i H_0 (2\infty)}
$$
so, there is a phase factor difference, not well defined.